# How to resolve 'PInvoke function has unbalanced the stack Error' in Windows Form Application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi

I have a Windows application, which uses the Windows API method to Drag the Winform from Client Area. Now when I release the mouse button it gives me the error **`"A call to PInvoke function 'xThemes!xThemes.API::SendMessage' has unbalanced the stack."`**

This error does produced when .net version is 3.5 but produces when version is greater than 3.5.

CS Page:

```
 private void titlebar_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //Function for form dragging.
            if (this.WindowState != FormWindowState.Maximized)
            {
                if (MouseButtons.ToString() == "Left")
                {
                    API.ReleaseCapture();
                    API.SendMessage(this.Handle, WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN, HT_CAPTION, 0);
                }
            }
        }
```

API class

```
//Windows API for resizing the window.
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, int lParam, int wParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);
```

Comment: Why are you marking these imports as `Cdecl`?

Comment: Your pinvoke declarations are just wrong.  They are StdCall, not Cdecl.  This probably went off the rails by the incorrect SendMessage() declaration, the lParam and wParam arguments are IntPtr, the return value is IntPtr.  This can go unnoticed for a while until you run the 64-bit version of your program.

Comment: @Thanks all .... you all are right, it should be StdCall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The change in API will fixed this error (Suggested by Hans Passant)...

```
//Windows API for resizing the window.
[DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, long lParam, long wParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool ReleaseCapture();

[DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int cmdShow);
```

Answer (score 1):

This means that your P/Invoke has some wrong definitions.  Usually in http://www.pinvoke.net you'll find good information about native windows API Calls. They're usually right (not ever!)

For SendMessage, I found the following definition:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, UInt32 Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Sounds like the problems is with the int x IntPtr. Following the msdn definition:

> The IntPtr type is designed to be an integer whose size is
>   platform-specific. That is, an instance of this type is expected to be
>   32-bits on 32-bit hardware and operating systems, and 64-bits on
>   64-bit hardware and operating systems.

In other words, using your imports in a 64 bits environment can be the answer to your question.